# Loop json object as array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

How can i loop the response to get all ids and names?
If the response like this:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Id": "4321",
      "Name": "Dog"
    },
    {
      "Id": "749869",
      "Name": "Cat"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can get all the ids and names using this code:

```
foreach (json_decode($response->content)->Data as $resp) {
    echo $resp->Id;
    echo $resp->Name;
}
```

But, if the response like this:

```
    {
      "Data": {
        "dog": {
          "Id": "4321",
          "Name": "Dog"
        },
        "cat": {
          "Id": "749869",
          "Name": "Cat"
        }
      }
    }
```

How can i get all the ids and names without knowing the amount of the array? Thank you.

Comment: ... the exact same way? That `foreach` loop will work identically with both of formats.

Comment: `foreach(json_decode($response->content)->Data as $k=>$v) { echo $v->Id; echo $v->Name; echo $k; }`

Comment: @Krisnadi I've just tried your `foreach` code and it's working for the second JSON too.

Comment: Read about [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). All the answers are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get PHP to read everything into an (associative where applicable) array.

```
foreach (json_decode($response->content, true)["Data"] as $resp) { //2nd parameter is to decode as array
    echo $resp["Id"];
    echo $resp["Name"];
}
```

Example run: https://eval.in/954621

Alternatively you can do the lazy thing and just cast:

```
foreach ((array)json_decode($response->content)->Data as $resp) {
    echo $resp->Id;
    echo $resp->Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to extract all ids into one array (I assume you mean all into one array), to use in a database query as an example. I would recommend you doing like this.

```
$ids = array_values(array_map(function($animal){
    return intval($animal['Id']);
}, json_decode($response->content, true)['Data']));
var_dump($ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

you do the same ! foreach loop would work on both.
the json response supposed to have the same format every time, unless you have a really weird API.

```
<?php

$response = json_decode($json);
foreach($response as $animal => $data) 
{
   echo $animal; 
   echo $data->id;
   echo $data->name;
}
```